# Prove that the center of a ring is a subring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

The center of a ring $R$ is $\{c\in R : cr=rc $ for every $ r \in R\}$. Prove that the center of a ring is a subring. What is the center of a commutative ring?

Is my solution right?

solution

You just need to prove that the centre is a ring within itself.

1. Associativity of both addition and multiplication is inherited from R, and distributivity of multiplication over addition is inherited from R.
2. Show that it is a group under addition: 
   Take a and b in the centre and r in R. 
   Then 
   $(a + b)r = ar + br = ra + rb = r(a + b)$

hence it is closed under addition. 
Show that $0$ (additive identity) is in the centre.

$0 = 0.r = r.0$ 
so $0$ is in the centre.

For a in the centre, there exists $-a$ in R such that $a + (-a) = 1 = (-a) + a$

Show that $-a$ is in the centre. 
Let r in R 
$0 = 0.r = (a + (-a))r = ar + (-a)r $
and 
$0 = r.0 = r(a + (-a)) = ra + r(-a) $

as $ ra = ar$, it follows that $(-a)r = r(-a) $
Hence inverses exist in the centre. 
So the centre is a group under +.

3. Show that the centre is closed under multiplication: 
   For a,b in the centre and r in R,# 
   $(ab)r = a(br) = a(rb) = (ar)b = (ra)b = r(ab) $

thus multiplication is closed. 
And show that 1 (the multiplicative identity) is in the centre. 
$1.r = r = r.1$
hence 1 is in the centre.

So the center is a subring of R.

The center of a commutative ring is the ring itself. (By definition the centre is the ring of all commutative elements.)

Comment: It is correct but showing the identity is superflous, as rings do not necciserily have an identity.

Comment: @ZelosMalum some authors impose that rings must have an identity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On the center of a ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592642/on-the-center-of-a-ring)

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is right, but unnecessarily long. When you want to prove that some nonempty set is a subring you have to use the [subring test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40677/the-subring-test). Denote the center of your ring by $Z(R)$, you only have to prove that $1\in Z(R)$ and if $x,y\in Z(R)$, then $x-y, x\cdot y\in Z(R)$. Since you have proved all that, then $Z(R)$ is a subring of $R$.

The answer to the other question is right too; the center of a commutative ring is the ring itself.

Answer (score 1):

Let C is the centre of a ring R and x, y are in C, then for all c in C,we have
xc=cx and yc=cy
Now, c(x-y)=cx-cy as distribitive law holds in C ,C being subset of R
So c(x-y)=xc-yc=(x-y)c which implies that x-y is in C. 
Now, c(xy)=(cx)y=(xc)y=x(cy)=x(yc)=(xy)c.
Which implies that xy is in C. 
Thus C is subring of R.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference